# django form not submitting due to slug and foreign key

Tags: django, forms, slug

My django cabin form is not submitting. I have applied foreign key and slug in my cabin's model and after that my form stopped getting submitted. whenever I enter all the fields and hit submit button,the form page is getting reloaded and no data is getting submitted.Most Importantly it is not showing any error so that I can fix it.I have tried and searched a lot about it and tried different things but still it didn't work. I am stuck to it. Please help!!

```
class Centre(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length =250)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
                             message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 10 digits allowed.")
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=10, blank=True)  # validators should be a list
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Centre, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


  class Cabin(models.Model):
     random_string = str(random.randint(100000, 999999))
     centre_name = models.ForeignKey(Centre, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
     code = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=False, unique=True, default=random_string)
     total_seats = models.IntegerField(blank='False')
     category=models.CharField(max_length=100, default=False)
     booked_date=models.DateField(blank='False')
     released_date=models.DateField(blank='False')
     price=models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=None)
     slug = models.SlugField(unique=False,default=None)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.category)
        super(Cabin, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


 In views.py file

 class CabinCreateView(CreateView):
     fields = '__all__'
     model = Cabin
     success_url = reverse_lazy("NewApp:logindex")


    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.cabin = Cabin.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])[0]
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())


   In my cabin template,

   <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <form method="POST">
                                             {% csrf_token %}
                                                {{ form.non_field_errors }}

                                                <div class="col col-md-12">
                                                <div class="fieldWrapper" >
                                                {{ form.centre_name.errors }}
                                                    <div class="form-group col col-md-3">
                                                        <label>Centre Name</label>
                                                        {{form.centre_name}}
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="form-group col col-md-3" style="float:right; margin-top=-80px;width=200%">
                                                    <label for="{{form.code.id_for_label}" style="margin-left:200px;width:200%;white-space:nowrap;">Code</label>
                                                     <input type="text" placeholder="Code" value="{{form.code.value}}" name="code" maxlength="6" id="id_code" style="width:500px; margin-left:200px;">
                                                </div>

                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col col-md-12">
                                                 <div class="form-group col col-md-3" style="float:right; margin-top=-80px;">
                                                <label for="{{form.total_seats.id_for_label}" style="margin-left:200px;width:200px;white-space:nowrap;">seats</label>
                                                 <input type="text" placeholder="seats" name="total_seats" id="id_total_seats" style="width:500px; margin-left:200px;">
                                                 </div>

                                                    <div class="fieldWrapper" >
                                                {{ form.category.errors }}

                                                 <div class="form-group col col-md-3" >

                                                    <label for="{{form.category.id_for_label}" style="margin-top:-40px">Category</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="category"  maxlength="100" id="id_category" placeholder="Category" style="width:500px";>
                                                 </div></div></div>

                                                <div class="col col-md-12">


                                                    <div class="fieldWrapper" >
                                                {{ form.released_date.errors }}

                                                 <div class="form-group col col-md-3" style="float:right; margin-top=-80px;">
                                                <label for="{{form.released_date.id_for_label}" style="margin-left:200px;width:200px;white-space:nowrap;">released date</label>
                                                 <input type="text" placeholder="%yyyy-mm-dd" name="released_date" id="id_released_date" style="width:500px; margin-left:200px;">
                                                 </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                <div class="fieldWrapper" >
                                                {{ form.booked_date.errors }}

                                                 <div class="form-group col col-md-3" >
                                                    <label for="{{form.booked_date.id_for_label}" style="margin-top:-40px">booked date</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="booked_date"   id="id_booked_date"  placeholder="%yyyy-mm-dd" style="width:500px";>
                                                 </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                 </div>


                                        <div class="col col-md-12">


                                        <div class="form-group col col-md-3" >
                                                    <label for="{{form.price.id_for_label}" style="margin-top:-40px">price</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="price"  maxlength="10" id="id_price" placeholder="in rupees" style="width:500px";>
                                                 </div>
                                            </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col col-md-3" >

                                                <input type="submit"  onclick="comparedate()" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" style=" height:30px;width:80px;padding-bottom:2em;"/>
                                                </div></div>

                                                </form>


                                        </div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is in your views.py file. You are telling the view that it should build a form including `__all__` of the fields on the model, but in your template you don't include the `slug` field. Since you have overridden the `save` method on the `Cabin` model to populate the `slug` field, I guess you don't want that displayed in the template.

You have two options for fixing this. You could add a hidden field to the template containing the slug field. Or, what I think is a better option, you can change the `fields` attribute on your view to exclude the `slug` field.

```py
 class CabinCreateView(CreateView):
     fields = ('centre_name', 'code', 'total_seats', 'category', 'booked_date', 'released_date', 'price',)
     model = Cabin
     success_url = reverse_lazy("NewApp:logindex")
```

P.S. This isn't a problem you are asking about, but I couldn't help noticing that you have what looks like multiple broken variables in your template. You might want to check if your label `for=""` attributes are working as expected.